# run-script alternative in Grails 3

Tags: grails

In Grails 2 there was a great `run-script` command that allowed to execute custom Groovy script *with all project classes available*. Is there something similar in Grails 3?

P.S. The only way we found is defining out own `RunScriptCommand` which implements `ApplicationCommand`. This command requires a separate gradle project, which we are not happy with. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative, you can write an `ApplicationContextCommand` see for example, the `schema-export` command:

https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/ff6fd5148f0acc90b477e6828eb2111031b038c4/grails-plugins/hibernate4/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/hibernate/commands/SchemaExportCommand.groovy

Which is implemented in the hibernate plugin. One you have implemented you need to add the JAR which it contains to your Gradle build script classpath.